# Make itemize breakable inside longtable

Tags: longtable, page-breaking, itemize

I wish to insert long itemized lists inside a `longtable`.

While itemize environments normally insert pagebreaks at adequate positions, they behave as if they were unbreakable when wrapped inside a longtable. How can I influence this behavior?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{10cm}|}
\begin{itemize}
    \item   \blindtext
    \item   \blindtext
    \item   \blindtext
    %\pagebreak
    \item   \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

When compiling the above, the first page stays empty while the `longtable` starts on the second page. The entire `\itemize` environment gets stuffed into a single page that overflows at the bottom.

I would like pagebreaks to be inserted anywhere: preferrably between two consecutive `\item` elements (or if an `\item` is too long, it may be broken up). Even inserting a manual `\pagebreak` (as hinted) will just widen the vertical space between the adjacent `\item` entries without producing the expected behavior.

I read elsewhere that this might have to do with some penalty values, but I couldn't quite figure out how to set them.

**EDIT:**
The above is an MWE. The real document is a report with very long lists of publications. I use a tabular structure because I need to reproduce an official Word template that has everything in tables. Occasionally I need to use double columns, split cells etc., to reproduce the template, so I really need some `longtable` type package.

A solution involving other tricks and packages is welcome. I hope you see what I want to achieve.

The real thing is a little more like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{\linewidth}|}

\hline
\textbf{A1. List all scientific publications} \\ \hline
Authors, titles, references, etc. \\ \hline

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\textbf{Journal papers}
\begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={[J\arabic*]},leftmargin=10mm,rightmargin=5mm]
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    % many many more items here
\end{enumerate}

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\textbf{Patents}
\begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={[P\arabic*]},leftmargin=10mm,rightmargin=5mm]
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    % many many more items here
\end{enumerate}

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\textbf{Open source code}
\begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={[O\arabic*]},leftmargin=10mm,rightmargin=5mm]
    \item Authors: \textit{Title} \url{https://example.com/software}.
    \item Authors: \textit{Title} \url{https://example.com/software}.
    \item Authors: \textit{Title} \url{https://example.com/software}.
    % many many more items here
\end{enumerate}

\\ \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it won't work. A table cell can not be broken. Why are you using a longtable at all?

Comment: I don't understand: isn't `longtable` designed precisely for the purpose of having tables that span over multiple pages, and are therefore breakable? In fact `longtable` breaks well as long as I don't use a long `itemize` inside it. Likewise, a bare `itemize` environment breaks well too. Why won't they break well when nested?

Comment: A longtable can only break between rows.

Comment: The breaking behavior is not directly related to the use of itemize but due to the itemize environment being inside if a single table row. As Bernard mentions, longtable can only add page breaks between rows not within rows.

Comment: Probably some background information on what exactly you want to obtain or an example that is closer to your actual table would be helpful here. Probably there is a better way to achieve the desired output.

Comment: @leandriis I have now provided a code example that is closer to the real thing. If you know a better way that achieves what I want that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose you not need `longtable`. Use just lists which can break between pages. `\hline` you can mimic with `\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\textbf{A1. List all scientific publications}

Authors, titles, references, etc. 

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\textbf{Journal papers}
\begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={[J\arabic*]},leftmargin=10mm,rightmargin=5mm]
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    \item Authors, ``Title,'' Journal, vol. 00, pp. 1234-4321, 2020.
    % many many more items here
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Patents}
\begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={[P\arabic*]},leftmargin=10mm,rightmargin=5mm]
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
    \item Authors. Title. Code. Publication number: 123456.
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Open source code}
\begin{enumerate}[start=1,label={[O\arabic*]},leftmargin=10mm,rightmargin=5mm]
    \item Authors: \textit{Title} \url{https://example.com/software}.
    \item Authors: \textit{Title} \url{https://example.com/software}.
    \item Authors: \textit{Title} \url{https://example.com/software}.
    % many many more items here
\end{enumerate}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's already something! But how about the vertical boundaries of the table? And what about multicolumn cells (not provided in my example, but sometimes needed in my real document)?

Comment: @jens, are vertical lines so important? If you like to have them, see `tcolorbox` package and their `breakable` boxes. `multirow` in one column table have not sense, actually, your question is now not clear.

Comment: Since I am trying to emulate an official Word template and the document goes through some kind of review process, I prefer to stick to the layout as faithfully as possible. By multirow/multicolum I meant to say that some *adjacent* cells (not the one containing my `enumerate` environment!) may contain more complex structures. For example, imagine that I wanted to split the uppermost cell containing "A1. List of all…" into two (left/right). With your technique I think it would become increasingly complex.

Comment: @jens, isn't it than simpler to stick with word? :-)

Comment: Sure, it's simpler! And it's what I'll do next time we write a report collaboratively, now that in my company we have Office 365! I love using LaTeX with git, but I'm sorry to say, sometimes I'm astonished as to how much effort and advanced TeX knowledge it takes to do some basic LaTeX fine-tuning. I thought my use case was a very simple and standard one, but the only solution seems to be to use a very comprehensive package like `tcolorbox`.